# Different projects Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, maven-2, spring-security, setup-project

I have a problem with a project refactor in my webs projects with **Spring MVC**, **Spring Security**, **Spring ORM**, **Hibernate with Maven**.

Now I have this situation:

I have two projects, one for normal users and other for experienced users. This projects have their spring security configuration, their controllers, their view and others configuration.

I wish have one project only for the controllers and the others projects with their views because a I need Rest API .

But I don't know how to configure spring security for securized the three projects and I don't know how to resolve views.